# write a graphql query based on schema

Tags: reactjs, rest, graphql, postman

I have a schema below based on which I need to find `defaultSubject` with respect to `SchoolCode`

I have tried multiple permutations and combinations but I couldn't find out the relation between `SchoolCode` and `defaultSubject`

**Schemas**

```
type Query {
 school(id: ID, schoolCode: String): School
}

type School {
    optionalSubjects: [String!]
    code: ID!
    defaultSubjects: String!
    defaultExams: String!
}

enum SchoolCode {
 kvr
 ttn
 rgs
 dps
 ris
}
```

**I tried:**

```
query ($schId:ID, $schCode: String){
    school(id:$schId,schoolCode:$schCode){
        optionalSubjects, defaultSubjects, defaultExams, code, id, name
    }
}

{
    "schCode":"dps",
    "schId":"23"
}

query myquery {
    schools {
        nodes {
            name, id, defaultSubjects
        }
    }
}
```

How can I write a query that would help me find a relation between defaultSubjects and SchooCode?

Comment: You're going to need to understand the underlying database schema to write your query. To simplify I would also suggest creating a `Subject` and `Exam` types which have a property that defines whether it is `optional` or `default`. `type School { subjects: [Subject] exams: [Exam] }`

Comment: But how's that going to help me find the relation between `SchoolCode` and `defaultSubjects`?

Comment: It's not. Using GraphQL to guess at the relationship between tables in your database  isn't going to help you. You need to look at the db schema itself and find the primary and foreign keys in the tables you're interested in.